# SQL Unpivot data out based on a join, is this possible?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, unpivot

I'm trying to eliminate having a long running list of insert queries in a stored procedure. This is for updating a smartsheet from SQL server (below is all SQL/SQL server).

I have a bunch of metrics on a pretty standard table. Small example below:

```
TABLE A

Site_Name    Revenue   Expenses  MiscOverhead
site 1        80000     10000       1000
site 2        90000     9000         500
site 3        50000     2000         200
```

Now, in order to update smartsheet, you need to have a row Id and a column Id. The row Id is not an issue however I need to bump Table A up against a mapping table that has the name of the column, and then the corresponding column Id. So for instance the mapping table would look similar to this:

```
TABLE B
ColumnName    ColumnId
Revenue        xyz11
Expenses       zzz33
MiscOverhead   jjj34
```

In order to get what I am looking for, the only way I know how to do this, is to write a bunch of union statements and multiple inserts into a temp table to get my output. Does anyone know of way of how to do this in a ***single*** query in sql? I wasn't sure if there was a way to do some type of fancy pivot join between the column name on Table A and B. Below is how the output data needs to look:

```
RESULT NEEDED
Site_Name    ColumnName         ColumnId     ColumnValue
site 1        Revenue             xyz11          80000
site 1        Expenses            zzz33          10000
site 1        MiscOverhead        jjj34          1000
site 2        Revenue             xyz11          90000
site 2        Expenses            jjj34          9000

etc.etc. for all sites
```

Any advice is appreciated thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming numerous or variable columns...  This will dynamically UNPIVOT your data without having to use dynamic SQL.

```
Select A.Site_Name
      ,ColumnName = C.Item
      ,ColumnID   = D.ColumnId
      ,ColumnValue= C.Value
 From  TableA A
 Cross Apply ( values ((Select A.* for XML RAW,Type))) B(XData)
 Cross Apply (
               Select Item  = replace(xAttr.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(100)'),'_x0020_',' ')
                     ,Value = xAttr.value('.','varchar(150)')   -- <<Use the appropriate datatype
                From  B.XData.nodes('//@*') xNode(xAttr)
            ) C
 Join  TableB D on C.Item=D.ColumnName  
 Where Item not in ('Site_Name','OtherCols','ToExclude')
```

**Results**

[image]

Comment: You can do it without the convert by using `TYPE` like this `Cross Apply ( values (Select A.* for XML RAW, TYPE) B(XData)` Also `.` is slow, use `text()[1]` instead. Also `//` descendant axis is slow, and unnecessary, you can just use `@*`

Comment: @Charlieface On 90K records generating 1.2MM rows, the TYPE vs convert() saved an average of  .07 seconds.   A good tip.   However, I can't seem to get your other suggestions working  https://dbfiddle.uk/xtxw8Dvp

Comment: Didn't realize you were using attributes. For attributes you *should* use `.` as it's a string anyway. And use `.nodes('/row/@*')`. https://dbfiddle.uk/Lgt7FDNy If you were using `, ELEMENTS` then you would get elements instead of attributes, in which case my points stand https://dbfiddle.uk/8nlzQTgA I'm not sure whether attributes or elements is faster, I would imagine attributes would be.

Comment: Thank you very much. This seems to be working however I'll have to figure out how this will work with columns with spaces in it. Right now it's excluding those rows. For instance, I have a column name that is "Total Capacity". It doesn't seem to be able to match because of the space. Not sure how to remedy that. It seems like it replaces a space with '_x0020_' so I can edit the join to replace that with a space. i'll give that a shot.

Comment: @user3494110  Yeah,  XML does not like columns with spaces.  The JSON approach is much cleaner but that requires 2016+

Comment: @user3494110  in CROSS APPLY C tweak ITEM with a replace   ... Select Item  = replace(xAttr.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(100)'),'_x0020_',' ')  ...

Comment: @user3494110 I updated CROSS APPLY C in my answer including a replace

Answer (score 0):

You can just unpivot using `CROSS APPLY (VALUES`

```sql
SELECT
  a.Site_Name,
  u.ColumnName,
  b.ColumnId,
  u.ColumnValue
FROM Table_A a
CROSS APPLY (VALUES
    ('Site_Name',    CAST(a.Site_Name AS nvarchar(max))),
    ('Revenue',      a.Revenue),
    ('Expenses',     a.Expenses),
    ('MiscOverhead', a.MiscOverhead)
) u(ColumnName, ColumnValue)
JOIN Table_B b ON b.ColumnName = u.ColumnName
```